# Count Distinct on multiple values within same column in SQL Aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, aggregation

Objective:

I wanted to show the number of distinct IDs for any combination selected.

In the below example, I have data at a granular level: ID level data.

I wanted to show the number of distinct IDs for each combination.

For this, I use count distinct which will give me '1' for the below combinations.

But let's say if I wanted to find the number of IDs who made both E-commerce and Face to face transactions, in that case, if I just use this data, I would be showing the sum of E-comm and Face to face and the result would be '2' instead of '1'.

[image]

And this is not limited to Ecom/Face to face. I wanted to apply the same logic for all columns.

Please let me know if you have any other alternative approach to address this issue.

Comment: There is no link in your question.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Hey sorry just now added the link.Please check

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand what 're you looking for. Please post the sample data as DDL+DML or formatted text a long side with the desired results. Not sure but it looks like you're looking for a conditional aggregation `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate in your table to get the distinct `id`s for each `TranType`:

```
SELECT TranType, COUNT(DISTINCT id) counter_distinct
FROM tablename
GROUP BY TranType
```

and then join to the table:

```
SELECT t.*, g.counter_distinct
FROM tablename t 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TranType, COUNT(DISTINCT id) counter_distinct
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY TranType
) g ON g.TranType = t.TranType
```

Or use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.TranType = t1.TranType) counter_distinct
FROM tablename t1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. But here I wanted to do a count distinct on IDs and not type

Comment: @kiva i misread the requirement. See my edited answer.

Comment: I didnt understand the query. So as per this query, I would be getting count distinct as '2' for all rows right?

Comment: @kiva For your sample data yes you will get 2.

Answer (score 0):

> But let's say if I wanted to find the number of IDs who made both E-commerce and Face to face transactions, in

You can get the list of ids using:

```
select id
from t
where tran_type in ('Ecomm', 'Face to face')
group by id
having count(distinct tran_type) = 2;
```

You can get the count using a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      where tran_type in ('Ecomm', 'Face to face')
      group by id
      having count(distinct tran_type) = 2
     ) i;
```